# Cloning OS install over network

Tags: networking, installation

Looking for solutions which will allow me to clone an operating system to several pc's at once over LAN?

It must support multiple operating systems (win. linux, mac). Using boot up media or network boot. The installer must run unattended (burning and inserting a boot media is ok). Please detail if any preparation is required for the source operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clonezilla server edition does uni/multicast cloning over the network using PXE.  It is server based, but can run on any old hardware you have laying around.  There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's well documented - http://clonezilla.org/